# 504 Gateway Time-out Error Python TableauScraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been using this script with [Tableau Scraper library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping) since October 2021, and it has been a game changer for our community for making and communicating decisions related to COVID-19.   Recently started getting an error:

504 Gateway Time-out

The server didn't respond in time.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I'm relatively new to python, so I'm hoping there is a way to improve my script.

```
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS
import pandas as pd


#Get Ada County Daily Case Data
url = "https://public.tableau.com/views/DPHIdahoCOVID-19Dashboard/HotSpots"

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)

# show original data for worksheet
ws = ts.getWorksheet("ReportDate(EPIDATE)")

#Get data as CSV
wb = ts.getWorkbook()
caseDataCSV = wb.getCsvData(sheetName="ReportDate(EPIDATE)")
#Select only Ada County Data
adaCaseDataCSV = caseDataCSV[caseDataCSV['County1'] == 'Ada']
#Group by date to get a daily count (not every record)
adaDailyCases = adaCaseDataCSV.groupby("Epidate")["Number of Records"].sum()

adaDailyCases.to_csv('//datamart/COVIDDashboards/scrapedData/AdaDailyCases.csv')
```

Comment: is this working in web browser? Do you get any HTML with warning or other explanation? I don't know how this library work but first: did you try to use `User-Agent` from real webbrowser? Did you use Sessions with cookies?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe they changed something on page and now module need also changes. But if you needs some Covid values then you can get free CSV files from GitHub [COVID-19 Data Repository by the Center for Systems Science and Engineering (CSSE) at Johns Hopkins University](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19). There are raw data and daily reports.

Comment: @furas Thank you for responding!  The error is occurring when I get the data as a CSV file. There isn't a trackback error in python, but when I read the CSV, it has the Gateway Timeout error instead of data.  I can access the data in the web browser, and I'm able to download it manually. I do have to use the crosstab file format though - maybe I can script that.

Comment: @furas I want to use the state of Idaho dashboard.  During the Omicron spike, our state had a very big back log of cases that were not reported to the CDC.  They are chipping away at it, but the CDC is counting these as new cases instead of cases from a few weeks ago so our numbers are off.